# NSInputStream subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinputstream

I implemented `NSInputStream` subclass like following:

ClassName: `SampleInputStream`

```
-(id)init{

self = [super init];

if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (NSInteger)read:(const uint8_t *)buffer
      maxLength:(NSUInteger)length{

   return 0;
}

- (BOOL)getBuffer:(uint8_t **)buffer length:(NSUInteger *)len{

   return YES;

}
```

After that I am calling this class from other class like this

```
SampleInputStream *obj = [[SampleInputStream alloc] init];
```

But the `read` method and `getBuffer` method are not calling.

Could you please suggest.

Comment: Do not use streams, you don't need it.

Comment: Why? Can I know the reason?

Comment: In `Apple` Doc of `NSInputStream`, they mentioned we can subclass right?

Comment: Because you don't know what you do.

Comment: If you know that please explain me

Comment: @iOS Why do you expect `-read:maxLength:` or `-getBuffer:length` to be executed? Do you send such messages?

Answer (score 0):

Go read documentation and samples. You don't understand what streams are for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188i